# Error if the @Local annotation is used (EJB)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

GIT: https://github.com/AndreaCatania/libreria

I have an ear file that contain two module, EJB and WAR.

I have this interface for EJB

```
@Remote
public interface Library2IFace{
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public String getText();
    public void setText(String text);
}
```

All works fine. The WAR module does the lockup of the EJB correctly.

When I set the Annotation @Local instead of @Remote I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ac.ejbsclient.ejb.Library2IFace$$$view3 cannot be cast to com.ac.ejbsclient.ejb.Library2IFace
com.ac.test.servlet.MyObj.<init>(MyObj.java:15)
com.ac.test.servlet.DeServlet.doGet(DeServlet.java:17)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**UPDATE**
The code of MyObj is:

```
public class MyObj{

    public MyObj(){
        try{
            lb1 = (LibraryIFace) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/"+NAME_VERSION_EAR+"/"+NAME_VERSION_EJBMODULE+"/LibraryBean");
            lb2 = (Library2IFace) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/"+NAME_VERSION_EAR+"/"+NAME_VERSION_EJBMODULE+"/Library2Bean");
        }catch( NamingException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        lb1.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return lb1.getName();
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        lb1.setText(text);
    }

    public String getText(){
        return lb1.getText();
    }

    public void setName2(String name){
        lb2.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName2(){
        return lb2.getName();
    }

    public void setText2(String text){
        lb2.setText(text);
    }

    public String getText2(){
        return lb2.getText();
    }

    public void createBook(int bookId, String name){
        lb1.createBook(bookId,name);
    }

    public Book getBook(int bookId){
        return lb1.getBook(bookId);
    }

    private static LibraryIFace lb1;
    private static Library2IFace lb2;
    private static final String NAME_VERSION_EAR = "libreriaEar";
    private static final String NAME_VERSION_EJBMODULE = "libreria-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT";
}
```

Comment: Is the EJB deployed inside the same project i.e. the same WAR file rather than in an external jar file?

Comment: can you paste your code in com.ac.test.servlet.DeServlet.doGet(DeServlet.java:17)

Comment: As suspected, the problem is that you're using `@Local` on an EJB that is defined in an external library to the WAR.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, the two modules are on the same ear which is deployed

Comment: `@Local` works for EJBs defined in **the same project**. In case of your war, the EJB must be declared inside of your WAR project e.g. create a package called `foo.bar.ejb` and define the EJB there. If the EJB is defined in an external jar and deployed together within an EAR then use `@Remote`.

Comment: Ok thanks, So what is the real use of @Local?

Comment: Yes, because the EJB must be local to the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72364/discussion-between-andrea-catania-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Comment: "If the EJB is defined in an external jar and deployed together within an EAR then use @Remote" -- you are wrong. You can use @Local without any problems. The key is to define proper classpath. If you're using maven then search for "skinny war": put EJB JAR into EARs lib/ folder and put correct classpath entry into WAR's MANIFEST.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, `@Local works for EJBs defined in the same project.` is simply not true.

Comment: @AndreaCatania, we would need to see the code in the MyObj constructor in order to diagnose your problem. You would find life easier if you used CDI and injection. i.e. Inject a MyObj into DeServlet and inject Library2IFace into MyObj.

Comment: @SteveC I've posted the code into the "question" as UPDATE. I've read that the "@Local" can be used when the project are in the same EAR or in the same JVM. I've deploy the EAR project but doesn't work.

Comment: Now you need to ensure that there is only one copy of Library2IFace in the entire EAR, and it should be in a jar in the EAR/lib directory or the owning ejb-jar. Your error suggests that there may be another copy of it in your WAR/WEB-INF/lib directory. @Ajan's suggestion is a common way of managing this.

Comment: @SteveC Yooooooooo it's working http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html, if you write a response I can vote you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the stack trace indicates that the caller has access to a different copy of the `Library2IFace` class, most likely in the war file's /WEB-INF/lib directory.

You need to ensure that there is only one copy of the class available in the entire EAR, and it should be in a jar in the EAR/lib directory or the owning ejb-jar.

@Ajan's suggestion is a common way of managing this.